# How do I create a Kentico Editable video web part

Tags: c#, webforms, content-management-system, kentico

I am trying to create an editable web part much like the Editable Image web part that comes as default. I see there is a class called CMSAbstractEditableWebPart that should be inherited from when creating an editable web part, but I cannot find a way to get the media selection onto the 'Page' tab rather than the 'Design' tab.

If anyone can shed some light on this that would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you want to do.  You can add a video into the editable text webpart on the page tab already.  How will this webpart differ than the editable text webpart with embedding a video?

Comment: To be honest I am very much exploring what I can do with kentico at the minute. the reason I wanted to create a new web part was because I wanted to use html5 video rather than a plugin. Can this be achieved in the editable text web part?

Comment: Use Youtube video widget. You can configure a widget zone on your page, so it will be available for editing for content editors on the Page tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one may be a bit more complex than just cloning the Editable Image and replace the image with a video file.  Videos (depending on if you're doing HTML5, flash, a youtube embed, etc) very in what HTML they need to have in order to render.

But otherwise, what i would do is first clone the Editable Image Webpart, and from there start checking how it renders, you will probably need to clone the CMS Module control as well and modify it.